# Equivalent characterization of Poisson processes

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-analysis, poisson-process

Let $\alpha>0$. We usually say that an $\mathbb N_0$-valued process $(N_t)_{t\ge0}$ on a filtered probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal A,(\mathcal F_t)_{t\ge0},\operatorname P)$ is **Poisson with intensity $\alpha$** if

1. $N_t-N_s$ is independent of $\mathcal F_s$ for all $t\ge s\ge0$;
2. $N_t\sim\operatorname{Poi}(t\alpha)$ for all $t\ge0$.

Now I've encountered a different definition replacing (2.) by

3. $f(t):=\operatorname E[N_t]<\infty$ for all $t\ge0$; and
4. $f$ is continuous.

> It's clear to me that (2.) implies (3.) and (4.). But how can we show the converse?

I'm aware of the following fact, which might be helpful to show the desired implication: If $g:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb C$ is right-continuous and $g(s+t)=g(s)g(t)$, then $g(t)=g(1)^t$ for all $t\ge0$.

Comment: I do not think the converse implication is true. If there is no typo, (1) and (2) define the *homogeneous* Poisson process (with a constant intensity). In contrast, (3) and (4) also hold for inomogeneous Poisson processes. See this [script](https://www.uni-muenster.de/Stochastik/lehre/WS1314/BachelorWT/Daten/StPro_Ross1.pdf).

Comment: @KurtG. Thank you for your comment. I guess you're right. Does a nonhomogeneous Poisson process have stationary increments? Or is this only true for homogeneous Poisson processes?

Comment: Page 17 of the script I linked has the answer: only true for homogeneous PP.

Comment: @KurtG. Thank you, I see. Just one last question: For a homogeneous Poisson process, we can show that its jump process is almost surely $\{0,1\}$-valued. Does this property hold for nonhomogeneous Poisson processes as well? Or may that have jumps larger than $1$?

Comment: The jumps of both processes are exactly one, only the probability that a jump occurs in an interval $[t_1,t_2]$ depends for the homogeneous PP on $t_2-t_1$ only while it depends on $t_1$ and $t_2$ separately for the non homogeneous PP. The script I linked looks pretty good. Much recommended.

Comment: @KurtG. The reason why I'm asking is that I struggle to prove that the process induced by a Poisson random measure (as defined [here](https://tu-dresden.de/mn/math/stochastik/das-institut/beschaeftigte/paolo-di-tella/ressourcen/dateien/Stochastic-Processes.pdf?lang=en#page=74)) has no jumps greater than $1$. I've tried to proceed as in the proof of the corresponding statement for homogeneous Poisson processes and ended up with the following problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4344959/47771. Maybe cou can take a look.

Comment: Paolo Di Tella shows in his very nice script on p.74 that the process induced by a Poisson random measure has no jumps greater than 1: $\Delta N^A_t=\mu(A\cap\{t\}\times\mathbb R)\le\mu(\{t\}\times\mathbb R)\in\{0,1\}\,.$

Comment: @KurtG. Sorry, I should have stressed that. Note that he is considering a special random measure; namely the jump measure corresponding to a càdlàg process. What I'm interested in is the process $N^B_t:=\pi(B\cap([0,t]\times E))$ for a general Poisson random measure $\pi$.

Comment: @KurtG. (i.e. $\pi$ is a random measure on $([0,\infty)\times E,\mathcal B([0,\infty))\otimes\mathcal E)$ s.t. $\pi(B)\in\mathbb N_0\cup\{\infty\}$ for all $B\in\mathcal B([0,\infty))\otimes\mathcal E$, $\mu_\pi(B):=\operatorname E[\pi(B)]=(\lambda\otimes\alpha)(B)$ for all $B\in\mathcal B([0,\infty))\otimes\mathcal E$, where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure and $\alpha$ is a measure on $(E,\mathcal E)$, and $\pi(B)$ is independent of $\mathcal F_s$ for all $s\ge0$ and $B\in\mathcal B((s,\infty))\otimes\mathcal E$ with $\mu_\pi(B)<\infty$.)