# Show convergence of measure of a sequence of sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, exponential-function

Let $\lambda$ denote the Lebesgue measure on $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ and $(E,\mathcal E,\alpha)$ be a measure space. Moreover, let $B\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R)\otimes\mathcal E$ and $$\lambda_{s,\:t}:=(\lambda\otimes\alpha)(B\cap((s,t]\times E))$$ for $t\ge s\ge0$.

> Let $T>0$. Are we able to show that $$\sum_{i=1}^{kT}\left[1-\left(1+\lambda_{\frac{i-1}k,\:\frac ik}\right)e^{-\lambda_{\frac{i-1}k,\:\frac ik}}\right]\xrightarrow{k\to\infty}0?\tag2$$

We've clearly got $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-(1+x)e^{-x}}x=\lim_{x\to0}xe^{-x}=0\tag3,$$ but the situation in $(2)$ is slightly different.

Using $(1)$, we have $$1-\left(1+\lambda_{\frac{i-1}k,\:\frac ik}\right)e^{-\lambda_{\frac{i-1}k,\:\frac ik}}\le1-\left(1+\lambda_{\frac{i-1}k,\:\frac ik}\right)e^{-\frac\alpha k}\tag4,$$ but this is obviously not sharp enough (just consider $B=\emptyset$).

Note that the claim is easy to establish (using $(3)$) when $B$ is of the form $B=\mathbb R\times A$ for some $A\in\mathcal E$.